# Pandas MultiIndex groupby retaining index levels

Tags: python, performance, pandas

After research I have found no similar questions on this or any other forum.

I'm grouping a MultiIndex dataframe by its inner level. The thing is, after grouping by I still want to know which were the "chosen values" on this inner index.

So I have something of the sort

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 3],
                   ['A', 2, 4],
                   ['A', 3, 6],
                   ['B', 1, 9],
                   ['B', 2, 10],
                   ['B', 4, 6]],
                  columns=pd.Index(['Name', 'Date', 'Value'], name='ColumnName')
                 ).set_index(['Name', 'Date'])

ColumnName         Value
Name    Date
A        1           3
         2           4
         3           6 
B        1           9
         2           10
         4           6
```

What I wanted is

```
ColumnName         Value
Name    Date
A        3           6
B        4           6
```

What I was capable of doing was using this command:

```
df.groupby(level=('Name')).last()
```

was retrieving this:

```
ColumnName         Value
Name    
A                    6
B                    6
```

Or, by using this command:

```
df.groupby(level=('Name','Date')).last()
```

retrieving an error.

Keep in mind that this is a performance sensitive application.

Thoughts ?

EDIT: Meanwhile I did submit a [feature request at GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13455)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `tail(1)` instead of `last()` on the groupby object, you get the desired behaviour:

```
In [22]: df.groupby(level='Name').tail(1)
Out[22]:
ColumnName  Value
Name Date
A    3          6
B    4          6
```

This is because `tail` acts like a 'filter' method, keeping the original index intact (but only returning certain rows, in this case the last row of each group). `last` does not do this, because this method will give you the last non-NaN value for each column in each group, not necessarily returning original rows.

---

OLD ANSWER (using `last`): You can rather simply achieve this using `groupby` by making the index level you want to retain in the groupby as a column:

```
In [44]: df.reset_index(level='Date').groupby(level=0).last()
Out[44]:
ColumnName  Date  Value
Name
A              3      6
B              4      6
```

And afterwards you can set it back as the index to obtain the desired result:

```
In [46]: df.reset_index(level='Date').groupby(level=0).last().set_index('Date', append=True)
Out[46]:
ColumnName  Value
Name Date
A    3          6
B    4          6
```

---

Since there was asked about performance, it is true that the groupby solution is slower on the example dataframe:

```
In [96]: %timeit get_slice(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 879 µs per loop

In [97]: %timeit df.reset_index(level='Date').groupby(level='Name').last().set_index('Date', append=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.75 ms per loop

In [220]: %timeit df.groupby(level='Name').tail(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop
```

But if you look at a bigger example dataframe, the difference is already much smaller (and the `last` method is even faster):

```
In [83]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(
             {'Value':np.random.randint(100, size=len(string.letters)*100)}, 
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(string.letters), range(100)],
                                              names=['Name', 'Date']))

In [84]: df1
Out[84]:
           Value
Name Date
a    0        13
     1         9
     2        11
     3        16
...          ...
Z    96       15
     97       20
     98       40
     99       91

[5200 rows x 1 columns]

In [85]: %timeit get_slice(df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.24 ms per loop

In [86]: %timeit df1.reset_index(level='Date').groupby(level='Name').last().set_index('Date', append=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.69 ms per loop

In [218]: %timeit df1.groupby(level='Name').tail(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

It will depend on the exact application of course, but in many cases such difference in performance won't be significant.

Comment: If you track the edits to mine and op's posts, you'll see op is interested in performance. We went through a number of solutions similar to this one.  Use timeit to compare.

Comment: I added some comparisons. It's true it is faster (although I suspect that if the number of groups becomes larger, the difference will be smaller).

Comment: @piRSquared I found an even simpler solution, and faster as well!

Comment: That's a good one.  Thing is, I already upvoted you on this answer.  Can't do it twice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This will get it done:

```
def get_slice(df):
    l0, l1 = df.index.levels
    b0, b1 = df.index.labels

    n = len(l0)
    myslice = range(n)

    for i in myslice:
        myslice[i] = (l0[i], l1[b1[b0 == i][-1]])

    return df.loc[myslice]
```

Timed

```
%%timeit
get_slice(df)

1000 loops, best of 3: 458 µs per loop
```

Comment: I see you edited your post.  Typically, put that as a consideration from the start.  I'll check for you.

Comment: Agreed with your edit. It's still pretty weird that this is not a native behavior. I'll look for a feature request section or something

Comment: I edited the post with a much better solution.  Though less intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Still I think there should be a native option to do so. I'll take a look at the code. Though I have no hope that I'll be able to make it myself.

Comment: BTW, this solution will not give the correct answer if you have duplicate values in the index (which is of course not necessarily the case in the OPs application), although that is probably solvable by using iloc instead of loc.

Comment: Great comments.  I prefer yours and Merlin's answers.  But I enjoyed trying to make the solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:: `reset_index()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 3],
                   ['A', 2, 4],
                   ['A', 3, 6],
                   ['B', 1, 9],
                   ['B', 2, 10],
                   ['B', 4, 6]],
                  columns=pd.Index(['Name', 'Date', 'Value'], name='ColumnName')
                 ).set_index(['Name', 'Date'])

df = df.reset_index()
df2 = df.groupby(["Name"])["Name","Date","Value" ].last()
df2.set_index(['Name', 'Date'], inplace=True)

#            Value
# Name Date       
# A    3         6
# B    4         6
```

Comment: If you track the edits to mine and op's posts, you'll see op is interested in performance. We went through a number of solutions similar to this one.  Use timeit to compare.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the op is looking for efficiency.  You may very well find a better solution.  Maybe even one that looks like something I tried already.  However, you should consider timing your solution as part of the solution.  Otherwise, it isn't obvious how your answer stacks up.  If it was a better solution, I'd hope the op would select yours over mine.  I wasn't clear with my last comment.  I was in a hurry to get to a meeting.